# How to configure Push Notifications for CloudMagic with out Google Play Services enabled?

Tags: google-play-services, push-notifications, nokia-xl

I am using Nokia XL.

I used to use AquaMail in Nokia XL with push notifications.

But for CloudMagic, it asks google play services for push notifications.

What's the alternative to use push notifications in CloudMagic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to an XDA post [by one of the CloudMagic developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=48714307&postcount=281):

> ... CloudMagic rely on Google play services for notifications

Since they built CloudMagic on top of Google's frameworks, trying to bypass it will at best result in loss of push notification functionality, but would more likely cause the app to crash, since it almost certainly assumes Play Services will be available while running. AquaMail must be receiving notifications through some other means.

You'll have to either install Google Play Services somehow or find a different mail client.